# flex box centering not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have been working with flex box recently and have the hand of positioning but justification is still being difficult.

I want X images to sit side by side in flex boxes, and then wrap when the page gets too small for them. This all works fine. However what isn't happening is the images inside the flex box aren't centering horizontally. I have tried every combo of justify-content, align-items, align-self etc to get it to work but I appear to be missing something.

here is the code

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.general_peer_request_display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.general_peer_request_box {
  flex: 1 1 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.general_peer_request_image {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  border: 3px double white;
  background: blue;
}

.general_peer_request_text {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
  width: 80px;
}

.general_peer_request_text:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="general_peer_request_display">
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: @LinkinTED the code added in the question is not the full code and doesn't reflect the behavior so no need to put as snippet, it can create confusion and make the question irrelevant ... if you want so, use the jsfiddle instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to add `margin:auto` inside the boxes OR make their container `display:flex` (what you forgot)

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.general_peer_request_display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.general_peer_request_box {
  flex: 1 1 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Or this instead of margin auto
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  */
}

.general_peer_request_image {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  border: 3px double white;
  background: blue;
  margin:auto; /*Added this*/
}

.general_peer_request_text {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
  width: 80px;
}

.general_peer_request_text:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="general_peer_request_display">
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="general_peer_request_box">
    <div class="general_peer_request_image" style="background: url('') center no-repeat;">
      <div class="general_peer_request_text">Neo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin: auto had been tried in a multitude of ways, and did not work then either - but you were right that adding display: flex; inside both the top and second level containers worked a treat - thanks very much!